# Shell Script msg() echo "${RED}$@${NOCOLOR}", What does it mean

Tags: shell, echo

I am new to Shell Scripting and I am trying to execute an existing script but am getting this error. line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'. Here is the script of trying to execute.

```
RED="\033[0;31m";
GREEN="\033[1;32m";
NOCOLOR="\033[0m"

msg()    echo "${RED}$@${NOCOLOR}"
green()  echo "${GREEN}$@${NOCOLOR}"
```

Can someone explain what this code is doing and how to fix it?

Comment: Functions are defined incorrectly.

Comment: You mean: `msg() { echo "${RED}$@${NOCOLOR}"; }` and `green() { echo "${GREEN}$@${NOCOLOR}"; }`

Comment: ...not that it's good form to be using `"$@"` in that context at all -- combining arguments into a single string is one of the (few) cases where `"$*"` is the more correct choice.

Comment: The `RED`, `GREEN` are ANSI escapes to change the foreground text color on VT compatible terminals. `NOCOLOR` is the ANSI escape to return the foreground state to normal (canceling the colored foreground and ensuring the terminal will be restored to normal when the script exits)